# JQGrid How to set imgpath or how to specify the location of images folder

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid and i was going through the jqgrid tutorial. i tried to set the imgpath but it does not work. i dont want to have all the images in the current directory. how do i define img path in jqgrid ? I did some research and the imgpath attribute may be deprecated (they still have it on the jqgrid wiki though !)

I am using the latest version of JQGrid. How do I specify the path to the images folder in this version ? Right now, I just copy the image folder where all my CSS files are and this works. Is there any other way. The problem is that in our project we have a designated images folder which is shared by all other applications and I am required to only use that folder.

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with jqGrid version 3.5 it uses jQuery UI CSS Framework. It means that jqGrid **don't have any images**. So the `imgpath` option of jqGrid is deprecated (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5)).

If your web server is in internet I don't recommend you to copy CSS images to your web site. You can just include the reference need to include `jquery-ui.css` from some CDN location. For example from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
```

The file `jquery-ui.css` contains **relative** paths to all images. For example `url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100.png)` which absolute location is `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100.png`. So if you do need to include the copy of CSS and the images you have to place `images` folder *relative to the path of* `jquery-ui.css`.

Comment: thanks oleg ! i can do that. do you think it will have a significant impact on performance ?

Comment: @user2334092: The most advantage of usage CDN location: many *other web sites* use **the same URL**, so the required data could be already in cache of web browser even if the user visit *your web site* at the first time. Loading of files from CDN location is quickly independent from the location of the user over the world.